# A partial match changes the Matcher's position

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

When using **Matcher's** `find()` method, a partial match returns false but the matcher's position moves anyway. A subsequent invocation of `find()` omits those partially matched characters.

Example of a partial match: the pattern `"[0-9]+:[0-9]"` against the input `"a3;9"`. This pattern doesn't match against any part of the input, so `find()` returns false, but the subpattern `"[0-9]+"` matches against `"3"`. If we change the pattern at this point and call `find()` again, the characters to the left of, and including the partial match, are not tested for a new match.

Note that pattern `"[0-9]:[0-9]"` (without the quantifier) doesn't produce this effect.

**Is this normal behaviour?**

Example: in the first for loop, the third pattern `[0-9]` matches against character `"9"` and `"3"` is not reported as a match. In the second loop, pattern `[0-9]` matches against character `"3"`.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String INPUT = "a3;9";
        String[] patterns = {"a", "[0-9]+:[0-9]", "[0-9]"};

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*").matcher(INPUT);

        System.out.printf("Input: %s%n", INPUT);
        matcher.reset();
        for (String s: patterns)
            testPattern(matcher, s);

        System.out.println("=======================================");

        patterns = new String[] {"a", "[0-9]:[0-9]", "[0-9]"};
        matcher.reset();
        for (String s: patterns)
            testPattern(matcher, s);
    }

    static void testPattern(Matcher m, String re) {     
        m.usePattern(Pattern.compile(re));
        System.out.printf("Using regex: %s%n", m.pattern().toString());

        // Testing for pattern
        if(m.find())
            System.out.printf("Found %s, end-pos: %d%n", m.group(), m.end());
    }
}
```

Comment: But `pattern1` fails to match.  Can you construct a simpler test case (i.e. with simpler regexes) that demonstrates precisely what you mean?

Comment: Simply use a new Matcher. Exploit `matcher.end()`, `matcher.locate` and such.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: `pattern1` is supposed to fail to match but matches partially and moves the position of `\G` two characters to the right, then `pattern2` fails to match as well, which is NOT supposed to happen.

Comment: @JoopEggen: how exactly? What is `matcher.locate` ?

Comment: I've edited my code to show `\G`'s position after each `find()` invocation. I've added `pattern3` which shows that the position has moved after `pattern1` has failed to match.

Comment: I agree something weird is going on here.  FWIW, I've concocted a simpler example (which is hopefully easier to read!) - http://ideone.com/r5XtuP.  (Note - it seems to be nothing to do with `\\G`.)

Comment: I've replaced the first "F9" (in "abcdF9") by "B3" to avoid confusion with the second "F9".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: it has to do with `\G`. If I didn't have to use `\G` I could simply set the matcher's region to an arbitrary position and continue matching against other patterns. This would be the solution. But if I change the matcher's region, `\G` is moved to thet beginning of the input (before the start of the region).

Comment: What I mean is, the strange behaviour seems to be unrelated to `\\G`.

Comment: Documentation on find says: __This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.__ If one interpretes successful as __without an error__ instead of __returns true__, the behaviour above shown here seems legit. As I'm really not an Java expert, I'm not sure, if the documentation can be interpreted that way...

Comment: I found something really odd... I added a pattern, that would only contain a search for `\\G`. This would be executed after the first search. Now for some reason B3 is found... Hope this helps

Comment: When doing do the position is still 4 though. I also noticed that putting the same thing at the beginning of the whole process will not find abcd anymore. I cannot explain why, but only note my testing results :D

Comment: `\G` is not a character. It's a boundary sitting between two characters. If you match against one or several characters, `\G` is moved after the last character. Maybe if you match against `\G`, there is no matching character so `\G` disappears.

Comment: Sorry I mean `lookingAt` i.o. `locate` - a kind of find at the current position only. Not sure whether that might be useful here.

Comment: @Cutter Then all other searches would fail wouldn't they?

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes `lookingAt()` seems to be the solution for what I'm trying to do here. It matches only against the beginning of the region. The patterns will work without `\G`. When a pattern is found, I have to update the region by invoking `matcher.region(matcher.end(), matcher.regionEnd())`. If you put that in an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @geisterfurz007: yes indeed. I still don't understand.

Comment: @Cutter Me neither. Could be a glitch in the matrix potentially...

Comment: Independent of `\G`, this problem can be reproduced while calling `usePattern` method.

Comment: [Here is a test code reproducing this weird behavior](http://ideone.com/DRNfFZ)  First test case uses `[0-9]+` and second one just `[0-9]` before `:`. See difference in final line of output of both test cases.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava I've simplified my post and copied your code as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matcher proposes three different kind of match operations (see javadoc)
- `matches` for an entire input match
- `find` for a traversal skipping unmatched
- `lookingAt` that does a partial match from the start of the sequence

When a pattern is found by `lookingAt` invoking `matcher.region(matcher.end(), matcher.regionEnd())` or such can be used for consecutive pattern.

*(Most of the credit goes to the OP self)*

Answer (score 1):

As per [Javadoc of `Matcher#usePattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#usePattern-java.util.regex.Pattern-):

> This method causes this matcher to lose information about the groups of the last match that occurred. **The matcher's position in the input is maintained and its last append position is unaffected.**

So as per this documentation `usePattern` only guarantees to lose information about the groups of the last match. All other state information in `Matcher` class is not reset in this method.

This is the actual code inside `usePattern` method that shows it is only initializing groups:

```
public Matcher usePattern(Pattern newPattern) {
    if (newPattern == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pattern cannot be null");
    parentPattern = newPattern;

    // Reallocate state storage
    int parentGroupCount = Math.max(newPattern.capturingGroupCount, 10);
    groups = new int[parentGroupCount * 2];
    locals = new int[newPattern.localCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < groups.length; i++)
        groups[i] = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < locals.length; i++)
        locals[i] = -1;
    return this;
}
```

Note that `Matcher` class has private variables `first` and `last` that are not exposed using any public methods. If we use `reflection` APIs then we can see evidence of what's going wrong here.

Check this code block:

```
public class UseMatcher {
    final static String INPUT = "a3#9";
    static Matcher m = Pattern.compile("").matcher("");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        executePatterns(new String[] {"a", "[0-9]+:[0-9]", "[0-9]"});
        executePatterns(new String[] {"a", "[0-9]:[0-9]", "[0-9]"});
    }

    static void executePatterns(String[] patterns) throws Exception {
        System.out.printf("================= \"%s\" ======================%n", INPUT);
        m.reset(INPUT);

        boolean found = false;
        for (String re: patterns) {
            m.usePattern(Pattern.compile(re));
            System.out.printf("first/last: %s/%s, Using regex: \"%s\"%n",
                   matcherField("first"), matcherField("last"), m.pattern());

            found = m.find();
            if (found) {
                System.out.printf("Found %s, end-pos: %d%n", m.group(), m.end());
            }
        }
    }

    static Object matcherField(String fieldName) throws Exception {
        Field field = m.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);    
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(m);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
================= "a3#9" ======================
first/last: -1/0, Using regex: "a"
Found a, end-pos: 1
first/last: 0/1, Using regex: "[0-9]+:[0-9]"
first/last: -1/2, Using regex: "[0-9]"
Found 9, end-pos: 4
================= "a3#9" ======================
first/last: -1/0, Using regex: "a"
Found a, end-pos: 1
first/last: 0/1, Using regex: "[0-9]:[0-9]"
first/last: -1/1, Using regex: "[0-9]"
Found 3, end-pos: 2
```

Check difference in `first/last` positions after applying patterns `"[0-9]+:[0-9]"` and `"[0-9]:[0-9]"`. In the 1st case `last` becomes `2` whereas in 2nd case `last` remains at `1`. Hence when call `find()` next time we get different matches i.e. `9 vs 3`.

---

#### FIX

Since it i evident that `matcher` is not resetting `last` position on every call of `usePattern`, we can call [overloaded `find(int Start)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find-int-) and supply end position from last successful `find` method call.

```
static void executePatterns(String[] patterns) throws Exception {
    System.out.printf("================= \"%s\" ======================%n", INPUT);
    m.reset(INPUT);

    boolean found = false;
    int nextStart = 0;
    for (String re: patterns) {
        m.usePattern(Pattern.compile(re));
        System.out.printf("first/last: %s/%s, Using regex: \"%s\"%n", matcherField("first"), matcherField("last"), m.pattern());

        found = m.find(nextStart);
        if (found) {
            System.out.printf("Found %s, end-pos: %d%n", m.group(), m.end());
            nextStart = m.end();
        }
    }
}
```

When we call it from same `main` method as shown above we will get following output:

```
================= "a3#9" ======================
first/last: -1/0, Using regex: "a"
Found a, end-pos: 1
first/last: 0/1, Using regex: "[0-9]+:[0-9]"
first/last: -1/2, Using regex: "[0-9]"
Found 3, end-pos: 2
================= "a3#9" ======================
first/last: -1/0, Using regex: "a"
Found a, end-pos: 1
first/last: 0/1, Using regex: "[0-9]:[0-9]"
first/last: -1/0, Using regex: "[0-9]"
Found 3, end-pos: 2
```

Even though this output still shows same `first/last` positions as in previous output, it does find **correct** substring `3` both the times using 2 different patterns due to use of `find(int start)` method.

- [**Here is Code demo for working fix**](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/3Sv)